# Grouping Dictionary Objects by secondary Id C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I've tried to group a Dictionary with this code:

```
Dictionary<int,MyClass> groupedItems  = 
               dict.GroupBy(r=> r.Value)
              .ToDictionary(t=> t.Key, t=> t.Select(r=> r.Key).ToList());
```

Both dict and groupedItems are of the same type.
Class is as follows:

```
internal class MyClass { private DateTime timeStamp;
    private string id;

    private int value;}
```

I've already parsed the file into dict with an entry counter.
Now I need to be able to group all MyClass obj by the object id.
So that I can calculate time from DateTime to the number of hours by all instances of a given id?

I would of cause try to avoid collections of collections if I can?

Comment: You said you tried - what happened? Did it error? Did it not give the result you expect? What's the question here?

Comment: I get the error: Cannot implicitly convert type. Looks like there is a problem with the LINQ expression?

Comment: That was pretty vital info to answering this question, for future reference ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary you're trying to fill has this signature:

```
Dictionary<int,MyClass> groupedItems  = ....
```

The object(s) you're trying to put into it:

```
.ToDictionary(t=> t.Key, t=> t.Select(r=> r.Key).ToList());
```

Will have this signature - `Dictionary<MyClass, IList<MyClass>>`

You need to change either the first or last line to make them in sync.

Comment: When I need to group by MyClass.id :)

Comment: I need to group by MyClass.id with LINQ how do I do this?